# How to return a single value from a database?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I want to return the id(int) from the database without having to do it this way

```
var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username.Equals(username) && x.Password.Equals(password));
return user.UserID;
```

Currently I have something like this:

```
return context.Users.Where(x => x.Username.Equals(username) && x.Password.Equals(password))
                  .Select(x => x.UserID);
```

But I receive the following error:

```
Cannot convert expression type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int>' to return type 'int'
```

Is it possible to do so? And if so how do I do it?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: add a .Single() method after your select.... or maybe even just Users.Single(....);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must materialize the result:

```
return context.Users.Where(x => x.Username.Equals(username) && 
    x.Password.Equals(password))
    .Select(x => x.UserID)
    .First(); // or FirstOrDefault(); // or .Single();
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured I was missing something easy! I'll mark it as the correct answer as soon as this board lets me do so! (10 min)

Answer (score 0):

```
context.Users.Find(x=>x.Username.Equals(username) && x.Password.Equals(password)).UserID;
```

You will need to handle Null Exception.